# APUE.H Error Linux C programming

Tags: c, linux, unix, gcc

I'm trying to execute the below program-
Within `APUE.3E -> filedir -> filetype.c` (this comes by default when I downloaded APUE.3E. I didn't make any changes)

but when I compile this is the error I'm receiving:

`myramya~/Documents/apue.3e/filedir$ gcc filetype.c -lm -o filetype
/tmp/cchPKE7K.o: In function main':
filetype.c:(.text+0x94): undefined reference to err_ret'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I'm using Linux Ubuntu. I have installed APUE.3E in Documents folder. I have administrator permissions. I wrote a simple Hello.c program and executed using:

`$ gcc hello.c -o hello`

and it worked without any issues.

Answer (score 2):

Your hello example works compiling in a single step with gcc because it does not call any functions in other files (except functions in the standard C library which allways gets linked in).

Your filetype.c makes calls to a function err_ret which is not within filetype.c but in some other source file.

When compiling bigger programs the work is usually done in two steps: First source files are compiled into object files by making one call to gcc with the flag -c for each source file. Then all object files are linked together with a single call to gcc with all object files. It is also possible to put object files together into libraries. Usually a Makefile is used to compile bigger projects.

Your specific case with apue.3e is well explained here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105483/compiling-code-from-apue

Comment: thank you very much. Now the error is gone. But after compiling I ran 'code' ./filetype 'code' then I tried 'code' ./a.out 'code' that gave me a bash error: no such file or directory. How do I see the output?

Comment: Do you have a file named 'code'? What was your command to link the program? Did that command include the flag `-o filetype`? If so, I guess that you should run your program with `./filetype` and maybe add some options to the command line. But I am not familiar at all with apue.

Comment: this is what I did: $ gcc filetype.c -o filetype -lapue and i didn't get any error this time. but when I tried to see th output: $ ./filetype and I'm not getting any output. it just goes to command prompt.

Comment: then I tried: $ ./a.out and received this message: bash: ./a.out: No such file or directory

Comment: The fact that ./filetype returns back to command prompt without any error message probably means that it ran successfully. But it is also possible to look at the return value of a program by studying the contents of $? ( `echo $?` ). By convention, a return value of 0 means that a program run successfylly and values other than 0 means that something failed.